# Apostrophe causes a query issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, t-sql, parameters

When I execute a query for the population of a table I get an error on only two occurrence. In particular, when the name field has some value like this:

```
K'Ogladbach
```

Now the apostrophe causes an issue, because the query interprets this command like a new value and this is wrong.
This is my structure for the query in SQL:

```
string sql = @"insert into Team (name, code, shortName, squadMarketValue, 
                    crestUrl, link_self, link_fixtures, link_players, caption) 
                    values ('" + item.name + "', '" + item.code + "', '" +
                    item.shortName + "', '" + item.squadMarketValue + "', '" +
                    item.crestUrl + "', '" + item._links.self.href + "', '" +
                    item._links.fixtures.href + "', '" + item._links.players.href + "', '" + 
                    campionato + "')";
```

how you can see each new value is rapresented by `' value '`,
so if in the value there's a `" ' "` it's a problem because the query failed the table population. Hopefully, there is a solution.

Comment: One more reason to use parameterized query

Comment: @HaroldFinch i wonder what you really trying to do? are you exporting the SQL data to CSV?

Comment: Learn more about SQL injection from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SqlParamerterized queries rather than raw SQL.  This will help prevent SQL Injection and also provide a robust solution.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Team (name) VALUES (@name)", con);

command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = item.name;
// Add the rest of the parameters here

command.ExecuteNonQuery();  // Execute the command
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlParamerterized queries is the best approach

You can also replace a ' with a '' in the data
That is not a double quote - it is two single quotes
E.G. K'Ogladbach to K''Ogladbach